# Applying conditions on a table SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: mysql

I am working on a table that holds the financial information for a medical company, i want to set the value of the financialApproval column to be determined by the Instalment column, so that if the the instalment column value >= to (0.5*TotalPrice) then set the financialApproval column to approve.

`Create Table FinancialDpt(
OrderID int,
TotalPrice decimal (4,4),
Instalment decimal (4,4),
FinancialApproval varchar (255),
constraint FK_OrderID Foreign Key (OrderID) references ExportOrder,
constraint PK_OrderID Primary Key (OrderID),
constraint CK_Instalment (Instalment >= '(.5 * TotalPrice)'))`

any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms188300.aspx is what you're looking for I believe.  A computed column can be set to be a calculation based on other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using triggers: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm

inside them you also can call stored procedures
I came up with an example, idk if it works (but should):

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `TRG_financialApproval`;
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_financialApproval` AFTER INSERT ON `FinancialDpt`
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
DECLARE amount DECIMAL(4,4);
SELECT CK_Instalment INTO @amount FROM `FinancialDpt` f WHERE        f.`CK_Instalment`>=0.5*f.TotalPrice;
IF @amount>0 THEN
    UPDATE `FinancialDpt` SET `FinancialApproval`='approve' WHERE `FinancialDpt`.OrderID=NEW.`id_place`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
;
```